# Can I enable SSL port for embedded LDAP in WSO2 identity server?

Tags: wso2, apacheds, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 identity server 5.0.0: I wasn't able to find an option in carbon.xml to configure the embedded LDAP port to use SSL. As we need to use ldaps instead of ldap when accessing the ldap remotely.
Adding an additional port beside the clear text port would also be an option.

Is this possible at all?  Could someone give me a pointer how to configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know, embedded LDAP does not supported to expose a SSL port. You can find the configuration file `embedded-ldap.xml`.  It does not contain any config like that.  However,  It is not recommended to use embedded LDAP in production setup.  Embedded LDAP has been just shipped with WSO2IS as default user store. In production you need to use separate user store which is running in separately.